# Flash AS3 if/else statement not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to execute this code in flash AS3, but it's not working correctly . In the body of my `If` condition, I set `myFlag = 2`, but the `if` condition always is True!!

Here is my code:

```
var myFlag:int = 1;
if (myFlag==1)
{
    s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dars1);
    function dars1(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        myFlag= 2;
        s1.gotoAndStop(25);
        s1.mouseEnabled = false;
        var darsRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("dars1.swf");
        var darsLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        darsLoader.load(darsRequest);
        addChild(darsLoader);
    }

}
else
{
    trace("NO-CLICK");

}
```

Comment: When flag = 1 you setup an event listener... Afterwards even if the flag equals 2, the listener is still present and still fires dars1 on mouseup... Dont you think so ?

Comment: As JBA wrote: your event listener is added already. You are not checking IN the event listener the condition - you should.

Comment: Do you figure out a solution?  upvote helpful answers, and accept an answer if it led to your solution. If you solution was different, answer the question yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your first two lines:

```
var myFlag:int = 1;  //You are setting the var to 1
if (myFlag==1) //Since you just set it to 1 on the preceding line, this will ALWAYS be true
{
```

Even though you set myFlag inside your if statement, the next time this block of code runs, you'll just be setting it back to 1 with the line `var myFlag:int=1`.

What you need to do, is move your `myFlag` var and it's initial value somewhere up the scope of your if statement.

Since you don't say where the code posted is running (main timeline? enter frame handler? mouse down handler? movie clip timeline?), it's hard to specifically help.

If it's the main timeline, then the code will only run once anyway so there is little point in having a flag.

If it's a mouse or enter frame event handler,  then move `var myFlag:int=1` to the main timeline and out of that event handler.

---

**EDIT**

Based off your comment, you just need to remove your button once it's clicked.  See the code comments

```
s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dars1,false,0,true); //best to use a few more parameters and make it a weak listener
function dars1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //load you swf
    var darsRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("dars1.swf");
    var darsLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    darsLoader.load(darsRequest);
    addChild(darsLoader);

    if(s1.parent) s1.parent.removeChild(s1); //if you want the button totally gone from the stage

    //or if your gotoAndStop(25) does something along the lines of not showing the button, keep that:

    s1.gotoAndStop(25);
    s1.mouseEnabled = false;
    s1.mouseChildren - false; //you might need this too

    //or remove the listener so the button doesn't dispatch a mouse up anymore
    s1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dars1,false);
}
```

Comment: For better help/answer,  please explain where the code your posted is in relation to your application,  and what you are trying to accomplish in the application

Comment: thanks guys for quickly reply.
i want load external swf just 1 time by click on button then disable button.
Now what do I do???

Answer (score 0):

You remove the event listener after its function is executed:

```
s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dars1);
function dars1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myFlag= 2;
    s1.gotoAndStop(25);
    s1.mouseEnabled = false;
    var darsRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("dars1.swf");
    var darsLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    darsLoader.load(darsRequest);
    addChild(darsLoader);
    s1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dars1);
}
```

Comment: thanks guys for quickly reply.
i want load external swf just 1 time by click on button then disable button.
Now what do I do???